# Check if a Specific multiprocess Process object is Running and Stop said Process with a Click of a Button in a Template?

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I can start a process <s>and stream the command line outputs to a template it until it ends</s> and render the template while the process is running using flask and jinja with this code:

```
@app.route('/tasks/<task>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def tasks(task):
    running_task = multiprocessing.current_process()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if task == 'training':
            running_task = train_task(create_path(app.config['ARCHITECTURES_DIRECTORY'],
                                                   get('architecture_name') + '.json'),
                                       create_path(app.config['DATASET_DIRECTORY'],
                                                   get('dataset_name')),
                                       int(get('desired_image_size')),
                                       int(get('num_epochs')),
                                       int(get('checkpoint_epochs')),
                                       int(get('batch_size')),
                                       'charsets/chars.txt',
                                       float(get('learning_rate')),
                                       get('optimizer'),
                                       getlist('metrics'),
                                       get('loss'))
        flash(task + " has started.")
    return render_template('tasks.html', task=running_task)

def train_task(architecture_config_file,
               dataset_dir,
               desired_image_size,
               num_epochs,
               checkpoint_epochs,
               batch_size,
               charset_file,
               learning_rate,
               optimizer,
               metrics,
               loss):
    task = Process(target=train_model,
                         args=(
                             architecture_config_file,
                             dataset_dir,
                             learning_rate,
                             metrics,
                             loss,
                             optimizer,
                             desired_image_size,
                             charset_file,
                             ' ',
                             num_epochs,
                             batch_size,
                             checkpoint_epochs
                         ))
    task.start()
    return task
```

How will I be able to do the following:

1. <s>Know if the process is running.</s>
2. Kill the process in case I don't want to let it finish.

Comment: Why do you run it as a subprocess in the first place? Would it not be better to run it as part of your program, since it is in Python already?

Comment: If I don’t run it as a subprocess, I’ll have to wait for the output before the page is loaded. I do intend load the page first then stream the output into the page as the process is running. Unfortunately, the process outputs logs it to the command line and I have no control over it.

Comment: But if it is a Python process it should be possible to change it to not write to `stdout`? Then you should be able to run it as a thread instead, I imagine. But maybe you are not the author of `train.py`?

Comment: I’m not the author of the library that train.py uses.

Comment: OK, that complicates things slightly, but you can always redirect stdout just before you call the library functions, and then reset it after the call. If that happens in many places, you can wrap it, using a decorator or something similar. It is a bit more complicated, but I would still prefer that to creating a subprocess, just to catch stdout.

Comment: The thing is, the library function is the one generating the stdout (well, it’s actually stderr for some reason).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But before making a call to the library, you can redirect `stdout` (and/or `stderr`) to a `StringIO()` object and then read from that when needed.

Comment: Care to provide some sample code as an answer?

Comment: Certainly, but it does not really answer the current question, as I am suggesting a different approach to your problem. The first thing would be to look at how `train.py` is calling the library and show how to catch `stodut` and `stderr` there. After that, you would still probably need a new thread, to run the library call, to allow a response to be sent back to the user directly. And finally you need a way to interact with the thread through your API. This needs to be broken down into multiple questions.

Comment: I guess I could update the question in such a way that I’m asking for a different approach if subprocess is not the way to go.

Comment: As a sidenote; using your current method of a `subprocess` call, you may be able to get a working solution using `training_process.poll()` and `training_process.terminate()` (or `training_process.kill()`) but I still advice you to do a more thorough change.

Comment: The only way a I can do that is to pass the subprocess variable (or its process id into the template) and when the button to terminate it is clicked, I can kill that process.

Comment: You probably shouldn't expose the process id as such, but you must keep a state in the backend and have a way to connect the frontend button press to the correct object. This you have to do no matter what, though. That won't be fixed by using the approach I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by exposing the name of the current running process like so in this template of running processes.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <h3>Running Tasks</h3>
    <ul class="collection black-text">
    {% if not task %}
        <li class="collection-item">No task is running.</li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="collection-item row">
            <ul>
                <li class="col s3">{{ task }}</li>
                <li class="col s3">
                    <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('terminate', task=task) }}">
                        <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn red">Terminate</button>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
{% block extra_script %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/toast.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        toast({{ get_flashed_messages()|tojson }})
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And here's the part that terminates the process:

```
@app.route('/terminate/<task>', methods=['POST'])
def terminate(task):
    was_terminated_manually = False
    for running_task in multiprocessing.active_children():
        if running_task.name == task:
            running_task.terminate()
            running_task.join()
            was_terminated_manually = True
            flash(running_task.name + " is terminated")
            break
    if not was_terminated_manually:
        flash(task + " was already terminated.")
    return redirect(url_for('tasks', task='view'))
```